# debug php script live

Tags: debugging, aptana

I want to debug my php script that involves other php and jquery scripts. I know debugger how it works. I want to see variables when I click the post button that upload images.  Is there a way to see that?
I use aptana

Comment: Use the `var_dump()` function. For example post requests: `var_dump($_POST);`. This function prints an out from what is posted. See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php

Comment: I want to use aptana debugger.

Comment: Than your question isn't clear enough.. But maybe this will help? http://php.tutorialhorizon.com/how-to-debug-php-in-aptana-studio/

Comment: I have a problem to debug via aptana. I have a php website, I want to see variable step by step. for example, it has an upload section, when I want to upload an image, it gives a message 'empty file'. I want to see step by step when I upload an image and response message.
how can I do that via aptana?